# Tkinter ScrolledText, how to automatically update the scrollbar when moving cursor to a given line?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I have a Tkinter `ScrolledText` filled with 100 lines of text:

```
import tkinter, tkinter.scrolledtext
root = tkinter.Tk('test')
text = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(master=root, wrap='none')
text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
text.insert(tkinter.END, ''.join("hello%i\n" % i for i in range(100)))
text.mark_set("insert", "1.1")  # cursor position at the start
text.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

When moving the cursor to the 50th line:

```
text.mark_set("insert", "50.1")
```

the cursor moves there indeed, but the scrollbar doesn't update accordingly.

**Question: how to automatically update the scrollbar position when the cursor position is moved to the nth line?**

[image]

Comment: The general solution is explained here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text widget has a method named `see` which will scroll to the given index.

```
text.mark_set("insert", "50.1")
text.see("insert")
```

From the canonical tcl/tk documentation:

> Adjusts the view in the window so that the character given by *index* is completely visible. If *index* is already visible then the command does nothing. If *index* is a short distance out of view, the command adjusts the view just enough to make *index* visible at the edge of the window. If *index* is far out of view, then the command centers *index* in the window.